# Uso para Fecha y Hora

Tags: variables, datetime, timestamp

Estoy haciendo mi BD en MySql, necesito un apoyo, voy a tener dos variables de Fecha y Hora e introducir una variable es para registro (FechaHora_Reg) y la otra es por si realizo alguna modificaciones (FechaHora_Mod) la variable de Modificaciones va a estar cada rato modificandose en cambio la primera variable no es una sola fecha y se predetermina.

Le dejo el codigo de mi BD

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Categoria_Permisos
(
Id_CategoriaPermisos INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nombre_CatPer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Siglas_CatPermisos VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Descripción VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Activo BINARY(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
FechaHora_Reg TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
FechaHora_Mod TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY(Id_CategoriaPermisos)
)
```

Como puede ver tengo las dos variables pero necesito una que sea estatica y la otra va ser constantemente modificada, ahora quiero que me ayuden de la siguiente manera, como debo declararlas para no tener problemas, yo las declaro asi y me sale un error

Este es el erro que me sale

> /* #1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP
>   column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause */

Me sale que solo debe haber una sola columna con esa declaración, por favor necesito que me ayuden.

Comment: El error dice que solo puede haber una columna con `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` como valor `DEFAULT`.  La columna `FechaHora_Mod` puedes declararla sin ningun valor `DEFAULT`.

Comment: es que cuando se registra la primera vez, ambas se cargan, luego si se hace alguna modificación solo se modifica la variable FechaHora_Mod y la otra variable se mantiene

Comment: Esa logica la defines tu en tu codigo.  La creacion de la tabla no tiene nada que ver con eso.

Answer (score 0):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow y paso a explicar el problema y la solución.

### El problema

Tu código no funciona porque posiblemente tengas una versión de MySQL anterior a 5.6.5. De hecho, [el manual de referencia indica lo siguiente](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> #### Propiedades automáticas de marca de tiempo antes de MySQL 5.6.5
>
> Antes de MySQL 5.6.5, el soporte para la inicialización y
>   actualización automáticas es más limitado:
>
> - `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` y `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` no se pueden usar con las columnas `DATETIME`.
> - `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` y `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` se pueden usar como máximo con una columna `TIMESTAMP` por tabla. No es
>     posible que la marca de tiempo actual sea el valor predeterminado para
>     una columna y el valor de actualización automática para otra columna.

El error `1293` es debido precisamente a la segunda restricción.

---

### La solución

El mismo manual de referencia dice que, en ese caso, puedes poner la columna `FechaHora_Reg` como `DEFAULT 0` (en ese caso tomará como valor predeterminado la marca del tiempo de creación de la fila, o sea funciona exactamente como `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` sin violar la restricción antes mencionada)  y usar el `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` para la columna `FechaHora_Mod`.

Otra cosa es que, aunque tu `CREATE TABLE` funcionase, **no haría lo que pretendes, porque falta algo importante que es la cláusula `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` que haría que esa columna cambie cuando se actualice la fila**.

Aplicando lo dicho, el código quedaría así:

#### `MySQL 5.6.4 -`

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Categoria_Permisos
(
    Id_CategoriaPermisos INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre_CatPer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Siglas_CatPermisos VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Descripción VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Activo BINARY(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    FechaHora_Reg TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    FechaHora_Mod TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                            ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id_CategoriaPermisos)
) ;
```

#### `MySQL 5.6.5 +`

En las versiones de MySQL 5.6.5+ no hay ningún problema con este código:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Categoria_Permisos
(
    Id_CategoriaPermisos INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre_CatPer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Siglas_CatPermisos VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Descripción VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Activo BINARY(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    FechaHora_Reg TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FechaHora_Mod TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                            ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id_CategoriaPermisos)
) ;
```

Comment: gracias estimado

Comment: @Ing.JP Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.